# asp.net proper async locking per cache key

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, async-await, locking

I am reading about great [AsyncLock library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock), but I have some questions.

Example from link has following line of the code:

```
private readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();
public async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
  using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  }
}
```

I tried to reuse this code in my ASP.NET controller, but I have some doubts.

Scenario mentioned above covers bacic locking where cache key is always the same, but how about if I have dynamic cache, such as in example below, and I would not want `ArticleId1` locks user loading `ArticleId2`.
Should each cache key has it's own `AsyncLock _mutex`?

Also, have I done right to convert mutex to static, due to fact that multiple users will share the lock?

```
private static readonly AsyncLock _mutexIndex = new AsyncLock();
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int articleId)
{

    var key = CacheKeysFor.Article.ById(articleId);
    ArticleModel cacheEntry;
    cacheEntry = _cache.Get<ArticleModel>(key);

    if (cacheEntry == null)
    {
        using (await _mutexIndex.LockAsync())
        {
            if (cacheEntry == null)
            {
                cacheEntry = SomeDatabaseCall
                _cache.Set(key, cacheEntry, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            }

        }
    }

    return View(cacheEntry);
}
```

Comment: And what is `_cache`? Is that MemoryCache?

Comment: @Evk at this point it's MemoryCache, but it could easily become Redis if we switch via dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going this route - yes, you need separate lock for each key. You can achieve that for example with `ConcurrentDictionary`:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<AsyncLock>> _keyLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<AsyncLock>>();

public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int articleId)
{    
    var key = CacheKeysFor.Article.ById(articleId);
    ArticleModel cacheEntry;
    cacheEntry = _cache.Get<ArticleModel>(key);

    if (cacheEntry == null)
    {
        var keyLock = _keyLocks.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new Lazy<AsyncLock>(() => new AsyncLock())).Value;
        using (await keyLock.LockAsync())
        {
            if (cacheEntry == null)
            {
                cacheEntry = SomeDatabaseCall
                _cache.Set(key, cacheEntry, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            }

        }
    }

    return View(cacheEntry);
}
```

Note that keys locks will accumulate over time. That is not a big problem unless you have many millions of them. If you do have millions of them - you can clear locks collection from time to time. Doing that is not safe and might allow multiple threads to enter protected block, but in this concrete case it seems to be not a problem either (because you use locks to just avoid expensive database call).

Comment: seems reasonable. Accumulating will not be an issue, since we restart app pools at least once per day. Thanks

Comment: I see. This is a way to prevent creating or trying to create several locks for the same key?

Comment: @Robert Well after more thinking I thnk my above comment is wrong. Even without lazy it will be safe. Problem with `GetOrAdd` without lazy is that it can execute delegate you pass there multiple times. So in this case, multiple `AsyncLock`s can be created while accessing the same key. But, only one of those `AsyncLock`s will be returned from both GetOrAdd calls, another one will be discarded. Since `AsyncLock` is not disposable, there is not much problem that some of them may be created and discarded.